# Toggle cloning of table row to another table with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've created an HTML table, each row has a button that, when clicked, will clone that row to another table. My problem is, I'm not sure how to then go about making the same button that cloned the row, to then delete the row from the second table when clicked a second time - kinda like a cloneToggle if such a thing existed.

Here is my code so far

```
$(document).on('click', "[class*=td-link]", function () {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr').html();
    $('.second-table').append('<tr>' + row + '</tr>');
});
```

Does the cloned row need to have a unique class/id for it to then be deleted with a second click of the 'td-link' link?

Here is the HTML

```
<table class="first-table">
    <tr>
        <td>info 1</td>
        <td>info 2</td>
        <td>info 3</td>
        <td><a class="td-link">+</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="second-table">
</table>
```

Comment: Can you include an example of your HTML too

Comment: I've updated it to include the HTML, thanks

Comment: Will definitely need way to create relationship. Does data in main table have any unique properties available on each row?

Comment: Each table row has a unique class if thats any help? (The table rows are created dynamically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play with the `data-*` attribute for this to work. So when generating your table make sure you find a way to set different values to the data attribute (Since I am not sure if its plain HTML or generating from some code). So your HTML and Jquery should look something like below

```js
$('.first-table').on('click', "[class*=td-link]", function () {
    var rowNumber = $(this).closest('tr').data('row-num');
   if($('.second-table tr[data-row-num="'+rowNumber+'"]').length){ //if it already exists then remove it
       $('.second-table tr[data-row-num="'+rowNumber+'"]').remove();
   }
   else{ // else add it

    var row = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
    $('.second-table').append(row);
   }       
});
```

```css
table{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="first-table">
  <tr data-row-num="1"> // note the data attribute
    <td>info 1</td>
    <td>info 2</td>
    <td>info 3</td>
    <td><a href="#"  class="td-link">+</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr data-row-num="2">
    <td>info 1</td>
    <td>info 2</td>
    <td>info 3</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="td-link">+</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr/>
<table class="second-table">
</table>
```

I have tested it and here is a [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/vjmdn484/) too

Let me know if this helps

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out. If this works, then this seems like a perfect solution to my problem.

Comment: Can simplify it also matching the data attribute to an ID on row created ... `$('#'+rowNumber).length`

Comment: @charlietfl yes definitely.

Comment: Thanks, finally got it all working. For some reason it would not work using .outerHTML, I had to use .html and then re-add the <tr> with data id within the .append(), hope this makes sense.

Comment: Noooo, you just had to use `clone()` I updated my code long back.. You dint use the latest one

Answer (score 0):

Rino's answer is correct but that won't work if you have multiple rows. I've changed that remove() part. This should work.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, my code was incorrect. Here's the working code:

```
var secondTable = $('.second-table');
var idCounter = 0;

$(document).on('click', "[class*=td-link]", function () {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    if(typeof(row.attr('clone-id')) != 'undefined') {
        secondTable.find('tr[clone-id=\''+ row.attr('clone-id') +'\']').remove();
      row.removeAttr('clone-id');
    } else {
        row.attr('clone-id', idCounter);
      var clone = row.clone();
      secondTable.append(clone);
      idCounter++;
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zqug893d/

Comment: Same problem...index won't match across both tables. It works when you only have one in each